# I have a 3d square wooden block puzzle with no instructions

Tags: puzzle-identification

[image: Wooden Blocks]

I have a square wooden alphabet block puzzle.  Over 50 years old.  It is 27 blocks glued into different shapes.  I believe one of the shapes is the empire state building and there was a list of other 3d shapes that could be formed.

I do not have the instructions with the available shapes.

Comment: Is there a question?

Answer (score 2):

This is called the Soma cube.  The goal is to reassemble the pieces to make a 3x3x3 cube.  You can find plenty of resources on Internet with different shapes you can do.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soma_cube

This one looks home-made, assembled by gluing together letter cubes.